# Pattern Recognition for File input in C

Tags: c, scanf

I was trying to get input from a file in C using scanf. The data in the file is as follows:

```
223234       <Justin>      <Riverside>
```

This is the following regex I tried:

```
FILE* fid;


    int id;
    char name[100], city[100];
    char dontcare1[40], dontcare3[40];
    char dontcare2,dontcare4[40],dontcare5;


    fid = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fid,"%d%[^<]%c%[^<]%c%[>]%c ",&id,&dontcare1[0],
                                            &dontcare2,&dontcare3[0],&dontcare4[0],
                                            &city[0],&dontcare5);
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, how would I account for whitespaces in the file without creating extra variables, this doesn't seem to pick up the city name enclosed in the brackets.

Comment: There are much better ways, although they all involve *not* using `scanf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `*scanf()` you can expect literal characters and one space can match many separators.

My example is simplified with `sscanf()` in order to avoid dealing with a file, but it works the same with `fscanf()`.

The trick here is to use `%n` in order to obtain the number of read characters till that point; this way, we ensure the last `>` literal has actually been read
(we cannot know that with the result of `*scanf()`)

```
/**
  gcc -std=c99 -o prog_c prog_c.c \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion \
      -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wvla \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
  const char *line="223234       <Justin>      <Riverside>";
  int id;
  char name[100], city[100];

  int n_read=-1;
  sscanf(line, "%d <%[^>]> <%[^>]>%n",
         &id, name, city, &n_read);
  if(n_read!=-1) // read till the end then updated
  {
    printf("id=%d\n", id);
    printf("name=%s\n", name);
    printf("city=%s\n", city);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When trying to open the file, it's useful to ensure that the file was actually opened successfully.

```
FILE *fid;
fid = fopen("path/to/file", "r");

if (fid == NULL){
    printf("Unable to open file. \n");
    return -1;
}
```

Actually addressing your problem, I'd probably just use `string.h`'s `strtok` function, then use a space as a delimiter.

Also, I wouldn't use `scanf`, but rather `fgets`... The reasons for this can be found in various other SO articles. The following is an *untested* solution.

```
        char line[100], line_parse[100]; // Buffer(s) to store lines upto 100
        char *ret; // token used for strtok

        // Read an integer and store read status in success.
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fPtrIn) != NULL)
        {
            // Copy the line for parsing, as strtok changes original string
            strcpy(line_parse, line);

            // Separate the line into tokens
            ret = strtok(line_parse, " ");
            
            while (ret != NULL)
            {/*do something with current field*/
                ret = strtok(NULL, " "); // Move onto next field
            }
```

Please be aware that `strtok` is not *thread-safe*. In multi-threaded code, you should therefore not use this function. Unfortunately, the ISO C standard itself does not provide a thread-safe version of the function. But many platforms provide such a function as an extension: On POSIX-compliant platforms (such as Linux), you can use the function [`strtok_r`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3p.html). On Microsoft Windows, you can use the function [`strtok_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtok-s-strtok-s-l-wcstok-s-wcstok-s-l-mbstok-s-mbstok-s-l?view=msvc-160). Both of these functions are thread-safe.

Comment: You might want to [remove the newline character that was read in by `fgets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) or add that character to the list of delimiters when calling the function `strtok`. Otherwise, the last field will contain the newline character.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this quite simply by reading the line into an array (buffer) and then parsing what you need from the line with `sscanf()`. Don't use `scanf()` directly as that opens you up to a whole array of pitfalls related to what characters remain unread in your input stream. Instead, do all input by reading a line at a time and then use `sscanf()` to parse the values from the buffer, just as you would with `scanf()`, but by using `fgets()` to read, you consume an entire line at a time, and what remains in your input stream does not depend on the success or failure of your conversions.

For example, you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024
#define NCMAX 100

int main (void) {
    
    char buf[MAXC],
        name[NCMAX],
        city[NCMAX];
    unsigned n;
    
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin))
        return 1;
    
    if (sscanf (buf, "%u <%99[^>]> <%99[^>]>", &n, name, city) != 3) {
        fputs ("error: invalid format", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf ("no.  : %u\nname : %s\ncity : %s\n", n, name, city);
}
```

The `sscanf()` format string is key. `"%u <%99[^>]> <%99[^>]>"` reads the number as an unsigned value, `<%99[^>]>` consumes the `'<'` and then the character class `%99[^>]` uses the *field-width* modifier of `99` to protect your array bounds and the class `[^>]` will read all characters not including `>` (it does the same for the `city` next). The conversion is ***Validated*** by ***Checking the Return*** to insure three valid conversions took place. If not, the error is handled.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in the file `dat/no_name_place.txt`, the file is simply redirected on `stdin` and read by the program resulting in:

```
$ ./bin/no_name_city < dat/no_name_place.txt
no.  : 223234
name : Justin
city : Riverside
```

Comment: The result of `sscanf()` gives `3` even if no `>` was read after the city. However, I don't know if it is important for this particular problem.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, because the last `'>'` is not part of the final conversion, so it cannot cause a *matching* or *input* failure. And no, I doubt it is important, it could likely be omitted from the *format-string* altogether. What is important is reading the city name including all character not a `'>'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use `scanf()`, the other answers seem to cover every aspect. This is an alternative, getting input character by character using `fgetc()` and `strcpy()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main(void)
{
    int id = 0, c = 0;
    char buff1[MAX_SIZE], buff2[MAX_SIZE];
    size_t i = 0U;
    FILE *fptr = NULL;

     if (!(fptr = fopen("test.txt", "r")))
     {
        perror("error opening file");
        return -1;
     }

    while ((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
    {
        if (isdigit(c)) /* maybe check INT_MAX here if you are planning to scan big numbers */
        {
            id = (id * 10) + (c - '0');
        }

        if (i != 0 && c == ' ')
        {
            buff2[i] = '\0';
            strcpy(buff1, buff2);
            i = 0U;
        }

        if (isalpha(c))
        {
            if (i < MAX_SIZE - 1)
            {
                buff2[i++] = c;
            }
            else
            {
                fputs("Buff full", stderr);
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    buff2[i] = '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `perror` may not work in this case, as it is not guaranteed that `fopen` will set `errno`, even if it fails. This is guaranteed by POSIX, but not ISO C. Therefore, you may want to set `errno` to `0` before the `fopen` call and only call `perror` if `errno != 0`. If `fopen` fails and `errno == 0`, then you might want to provide a generic error message instead.